# Missing \begin{document}

Tags: errors, document-classes

I was submitting a manuscript in aps journal using `revtex4-2`, suddenly this error appears. Unfortunately, I do not know what part is the main cause, thus I attach my preamble and the log file. I really appreciate any help
Thanks in advance

```
\documentclass[aps,prapplied,twocolumn,floatfix,footinbib,notitlepage,superscriptaddress,groupaddress,showpacs,showkeys]{revtex4-2}%,caption
\usepackage{graphicx,times,bm,bbm,bbold,amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,dsfont,hyperref,mathrsfs,color,cancel}
\pdfminorversion=7
\usepackage{adjustbox}%,makecell
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[caption=false, justification=centerlast]{subfig}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\apptocmd{\thebibliography}{\raggedright}{}{}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{textcomp,gensymb}
\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}
\newcommand{\acot}{\cot^{-1}}
\begin{document}    
    \preprint{AIP/123-QED}
    \title[Sample title]{a new method}  
\author{}
\affiliation{}
    \begin{abstract} 
    \end{abstract}
    \keywords{}
    \maketitle

    \section{Introduction}\label{sec:introduction}
    kjh h ih ajkdh akshdj xnhsdjxn iosp;'., bgsajskl

\providecommand{\noopsort}[1]{}\providecommand{\singleletter}[1]{#1}%
    
    \end{document}
```

and the logfile

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.8.28) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.10.13) 13 OCT 2022 18:32
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**./aipsamp.tex
(aipsamp.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2022-09-28>
(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/revtex\revtex4-2.cls

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
... 
l.1 C
lass revtex4-2 Warning: No type size specified, using default 10.
You're in trouble here. Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.

Missing character: There is no C in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
…..

Overfull \hbox (20.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 1--2
[]
[]


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
... 
l.3 (
C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/revtex\aps10pt4...

You're in trouble here. Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.

Missing character: There is no ( in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no C in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no : in font nullfont!
! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 (C:\Users
\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/revtex\aps10pt4...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 (C:\Users\Sara


Missing character: There is no / in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 ...\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/revtex\aps
10pt4-2.rtx
Missing character: There is no 1 in font nullfont!
!
! Undefined control sequence.
l.7 ) (C:\Users
\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/textcase\text...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.7 ) (C:\Users\Sara
\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/textcase\text...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.7 ) (C:\Users\Sara\AppData
\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/textcase\text...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.

Missing character: There is no : in font nullfont!
! Undefined control sequence.
l.11 ) (C:\Users
\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/url\url.sty
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.11 ) (C:\Users\Sara
\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/url\url.sty
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.11 ) (C:\Users\Sara\AppData
\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/url\url.sty
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.11 ) (C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local
\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/url\url.sty
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.11 ) (C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs
\MiKTeX\tex/latex/url\url.sty
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.11 ...Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
\tex/latex/url\url.sty
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.



Missing character: There is no y in font nullfont!
! Undefined control sequence.
l.12 \Urlmuskip
=\muskip16
Missing character: There is no = in font nullfont!
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
P
l.13 P
ackage: url 2013/09/16 ver 3.4 Verb mode for urls, etc.
The unit of measurement in math glue must be mu.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

Missing character: There is no C in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no : in font nullfont!
! Undefined control sequence.
l.15 (C:\Users
\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/natbib\natbib.sty
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.15 (C:\Users\Sara
\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/natbib\natbib.sty
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Missing character: There is no b in font nullfont!
! Undefined control sequence.
l.15 ...al\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/natbib\natbib
.sty
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Missing character: There is no . in font nullfont!
!
Missing character: There is no ) in font nullfont!
! Undefined control sequence.
l.17 \bibhang
=\skip49
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Missing character: There is no = in font nullfont!
! Undefined control sequence.
l.18 \bibsep
=\skip50
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Missing character: There is no L in font nullfont!
\citation{o}
! Undefined control sequence.
<write> ...: Citation `\@citeb ' on page \thepage 
\space undefined\on@line .
l.19 LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite o
n input line 694.
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `o' on page undefined on input line 19.

Missing character: There is no ] in font nullfont!
! Undefined control sequence.
l.20 \c@NAT@ctr
=\count266
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Missing character: There is no = in font nullfont!
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
)
l.21 )
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

Missing character: There is no ) in font nullfont!
!
Missing character: There is no s in font nullfont!
! Undefined control sequence.
l.22 ...x4-2 Info: Repairing natbib's \BibitemShut
on input line 7665.
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Missing character: There is no o in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no n in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no i in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no n in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no p in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no u in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no i in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no n in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 7 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 6 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 6 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 5 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no . in font nullfont!

Overfull \hbox (20.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 3--23
[]
[]


Overfull \hbox (5.43053pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 3--23
[]
[]


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
... 
l.24 (
C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/revtex\revsymb...

You're in trouble here. Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.

Missing character: There is no ( in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no C in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no : in font nullfont!
! Undefined control sequence.
l.24 (C:\Users
\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/revtex\revsymb...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.24 (C:\Users\Sara
\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/revtex\revsymb...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.24 (C:\Users\Sara\AppData
\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/revtex\revsymb...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.24 (C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local
\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/revtex\revsymb...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


Missing character: There is no x in font nullfont!
! Undefined control sequence.
l.24 ...l\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/revtex\revsymb
4-2.sty
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Missing character: There is no 4 in font nullfont!

l.27 LaTeX Info: Redefining \REV@mathfrak
on input line 128.
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Missing character: There is no o in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no : in font nullfont!
! Undefined control sequence.
l.29 (C:\Users
\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graph...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.29 (C:\Users\Sara
\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graph...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.29 ...s\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex
/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Missing character: There is no / in font nullfont!
!
Missing character: There is no s in font nullfont!
! Undefined control sequence.
l.29 ...rograms\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx
.sty
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Missing character: There is no . in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ) in font nullfont!

Overfull \hbox (20.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 24--31
[]
[]


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
... 
l.32 (
C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyva...

You're in trouble here. Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.

Missing character: There is no ( in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no C in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no : in font nullfont!
! Undefined control sequence.
l.32 (C:\Users
\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyva...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


Missing character: There is no c in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no s in font nullfont!
! Undefined control sequence.
l.32 ...\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval
.sty
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Missing character: There is no . in font nullfont!
!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
! Undefined control sequence.
l.34 \KV@toks@
=\toks18
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Missing character: There is no = in font nullfont!
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
)
l.35 )
A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in.
You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections
so that I will find a matching right brace soon.
(If you're confused by all this, try typing `I}' now.)

)
Runaway text?
) (C:\Users \Sara \AppData \Local \Programs \MiKTeX \tex /latex/gra\ETC.
! File ended while scanning text of \toks.
<inserted text> 
}
l.2 \usepackage
{graphicx,times,bm,bbm,bbold,amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,dsfont,...
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

)
Runaway text?
) (C:\Users \Sara \AppData \Local \Programs \MiKTeX \tex /latex/gra\ETC.
! File ended while scanning text of \toks.
<inserted text> 
}
<*> ./aipsamp.tex
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

! Emergency stop.
<*> ./aipsamp.tex
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
1669 strings out of 475385
21889 string characters out of 2776434
419191 words of memory out of 3000000
23144 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
469567 words of font info for 29 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
33i,2n,37p,279b,93s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,80000s
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

and

```
Class revtex4-2 Warning: No type size specified, using default 10.

(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/revtex\aps10pt4-2.rtx
File: aps10pt4-2 2020/10/03 4.2e (https://journals.aps.org/revtex/ for document
ation)
Class revtex4-2 Info: RevTeX pointsize 10pt selected on input line 39.
) (C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/textcase\textcase.st
y
Package: textcase 2022/06/12 v1.02 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
Package textcase Info: Defining Legacy names on input line 20.
) (C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/url\url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/natbib\natbib.sty
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip49
\bibsep=\skip50
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count266
)
Class revtex4-2 Info: Repairing natbib's \BibitemShut on input line 7665.

(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/revtex\revsymb4-2.sty
Package: revsymb4-2 2020/10/03 4.2e (https://journals.aps.org/revtex/ for docum
entation)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \REV@mathfrak on input line 128.
))
(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks18
)
(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.
cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.

(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.de
f
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen138
\Gin@req@width=\dimen139
) (C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/psnfss\times.sty
Package: times 2020/03/25 PSNFSS-v9.3 (SPQR)
```

Comment: Using `\documentclass{revtex4-2}` I don't get an error message.

Comment: Thank you.  Do you mean  what I sent dose not have any problem? So Why I got so many errors :(

Comment: Not sure.  You may have a damaged copy of revtex4-2, or a newer or older version version than mine (I update every week).

Comment: Unfortunately  all of my tex files have faced  with this problem.

Comment: Send full log file, not only a part.

Comment: @wipt the log file includes 70000 words (full of similar errors)!!! I attached 12 pages of it. Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: @John Kormylo I updated my files but nothing changed. Thank you.

Comment: show the start of `C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/revtex\revtex4-2.cls` it appears to have the text `Class revtex` on line 1, not in a comment (which would mean that is the wrong file)

Comment: @David Carlisle. I am very sorry. I do not understand your mean and do not know how I can fix it

Comment: Your error indicates that `C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/revtex\revtex4-2.cls` is not the right file. But if you show what you have there we can say more. Unrelated do you _really_ use all these packages at once `graphicx,times,bm,bbm,bbold,amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,dsfont,hyperref,mathrsfs,color,cancel` it seems rather unlikely, certainly `bm` should be loaded after other font packages not before, but bbm bbold dsfont all defining double-struck letters like |N why all of them??

Comment: also `\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}` in a journal submission??

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you for your response.  I just  downloaded ```revtex4-2``` and  change nothing.  I think latex is very extensive. I really know very little about it. I attached the first page of what you want. I really appreciate your help

Comment: "dowloaded" ? You should not have to download anything revtex is part of miktex. If that last code block prefixed with your "and" is your `.cls` file then you have saved a log file over the source and removed revtex. Delete that directory and get miktex to update revtex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you are right. John proposed that may be my ```revtex4-2``` is damaged. I started to download and I could not do anything :(. Sorry I am very tired and so messed up. I did not expect some thing like this when I was submitting a manuscript after a long time harworking

Comment: Axcuallly, any of your sty files could be dmaged, or even the TeX engine.  All we know is that the error is peculiar to your setup.  BTW, the log file should include a filename and line number with the error message.

Comment: @JohnKormylo thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The log file is complaining about text being set in the preamble ("missing begin document") and before fonts have been set up ("nullfont")

```
Missing character: There is no C in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
```

specifically means line 1 of `revtex4-2.cls` contains text `Cl...`  which it should not.

Your later edit confirms this and shows the file starts

```
Class revtex4-2 Warning: No type size specified, using default 10.

(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/revtex\aps10pt4-2.rtx
File: aps10pt4-2 2020/10/03 4.2e (https://journals.aps.org/revtex/ for document
ation)
```

This is clearly a log file of an earlier run you have made, but instead of being in `somefile.log` it has been saved as `revtex4-2.cls` so removing the real revtex code from your system.

You need to delete that file then use the miktex console to force a re-install of revtex.

Comment: I do not forget your help. Very thanks for your explanation with details.